# why I can not delete node_modules directory on mac?

Tags: node.js, macos

I can not delete `node_modules` directory on Mac. I tried using `rm -rf` command . 
I also tried using `rimraf` from `npm` but not working. It gives error:

```
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/rimraf/bin.js:47
      throw er
      ^

Error: ENOTEMPTY: directory not empty, rmdir 'mustDelete/node_modules/react-native/third-party/boost_1_63_0'
```

any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Finder application to delete it.

What error do you get with `rm -rf`?